# Vigenère Cipher problem in competitive programming

Tags: python, performance

I've just started doing programming problems.

https://icpcarchive.ecs.baylor.edu/external/58/p5880.pdf

The code below works fine, but my run time is 2.715 seconds and the time limit is 3 seconds.

How can I improve speed of this code?

*I've already started to use `sys.stdin` instead of `input()`.*

```
import string
import sys


while True:
    key = sys.stdin.readline().strip()
    key = int(key) if key.isdigit() else key
    if key == 0: break

    decrypted_msg = sys.stdin.readline().strip()
    decrypted_msg = int(decrypted_msg) if decrypted_msg.isdigit() else decrypted_msg
    if decrypted_msg == 0: break

    key = (len(decrypted_msg)//len(key) + 1) * key
    key = key[0:len(decrypted_msg)]

    encrypted_msg = ""

    for i in range(len(decrypted_msg)):
        key_idx = string.ascii_uppercase.index(key[i])
        deciphered_idx = string.ascii_uppercase.index(decrypted_msg[i])

        enciphered_idx = (deciphered_idx + key_idx + 1) % len(string.ascii_uppercase)
        encrypted_msg += string.ascii_uppercase[enciphered_idx]

    print(encrypted_msg)
```

Comment: Where can solutions be submitted?

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Thanks for providing a link to the specification, but do note that a question should be complete in itself. Please [edit] to [include a short description of the requirements **in the body of the question**.](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1993) Obviously, you should take care not to infringe copyrights in the process of fixing this.

Answer (score 14):

### Comments

- `decrypted_msg` is misleading. It's not decrypted but rather "not encrypted". But really just call it "plaintext", as the problem statement does.
- Similarly, "enciphered" and "encrypted" are not just inconsistent (make up your mind), but go against the problem statement's term "ciphertext".
- The end-signal string `'0'` can simply be checked as a string.
- No need to check the plaintext against `'0'`.
- Mapping `str.strip` over `sys.stdin` makes the code a bit nicer. We can even use a nice `for` statement then.
- Better just `zip` the plaintext and key instead of iterating over indices.
- Searching the letters in the alphabet string isn't super terrible, but it's apparently faster to look up letter pairs in a dictionary.
- [`itertools.cycle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) is a nicer (and I think faster) way to cycle the key.
- Repeatedly extending a string with `+=` might [degrade to quadratic time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44487537/12671057) overall. Better use `''.join` on an iterable.
- A little time can be saved by storing `string.ascii_uppercase.index` in a variable instead of looking up the attributes `ascii_uppercase` and `index` over and over again.

### Solution 1: My fastest<sup>[*]</sup>, using a lookup-table mapping letter pairs to single letters

This gets accepted in 0.382 seconds [here](https://icpcarchive.ecs.baylor.edu/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&page=show_problem&problem=3891), where I believe you submitted yours (tried four times, impressively always got the exact same time).

[*] In my [other answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/256478/219610) benchmarking a worst case, actually my solution 3 is fastest.

```
import sys
from itertools import cycle
from string import ascii_uppercase as abc

table = {(abc[i], abc[j]): abc[(i + j + 1) % 26]
         for i in range(26)
         for j in range(26)}.get

lines = map(str.strip, sys.stdin)
for key in lines:
    if key == '0':
        break
    plaintext = next(lines)

    print(''.join(map(table, zip(plaintext, cycle(key)))))
```

I did get it down to 0.372 seconds by using `sys.stdout.write`, but meh, not worth it.

### Solution 2: My fastest with `str.index`:

Here's the fastest I got with `str.index`, got accepted in 0.699 seconds. Note that my `bcd` is *twice* the alphabet and starts with "B", so I can use `bcd[p + k]` instead of the slower `abc[(p + k + 1) % 26]`.

```
from string import ascii_uppercase as abc
import sys
from itertools import cycle

index = abc.index
bcd = abc[1:] + abc

lines = map(str.strip, sys.stdin)
for key in lines:
    if key == '0':
        break
    plaintext = next(lines)

    key = cycle(map(index, key))
    plaintext = map(index, plaintext)
    
    print(''.join([bcd[p + k] for p, k in zip(plaintext, key)]))
```

### Solution 3: O(|key|) Python operations

Since the plaintext has up to 100,000 letters but the key has only up to 1,000 letters, and since Python operations are slow, I also tried doing just O(|key|) Python operations instead of O(|plaintext|) Python operations. By using `str.translate`. For example if the key is `'KEY'`, then the entire string slice `plaintext[0::3]` is translated with the key letter `'K'`. And `[1::3]` and `[2::3]` get translated with `'E'` and `'Y'`, respectively. Sadly, it was slower, got accepted in 0.985 seconds:

```
import sys
from string import ascii_uppercase as abc

tables = {c: str.maketrans(abc, abc[i:] + abc[:i])
          for i, c in enumerate(abc, 1)}

lines = map(str.strip, sys.stdin)
for key in lines:
    if key == '0':
        break
    plaintext = next(lines)

    ciphertext = [None] * len(plaintext)
    n = len(key)
    for i, k in enumerate(key):
        ciphertext[i::n] = plaintext[i::n].translate(tables[k])

    print(''.join(ciphertext))
```

### Solution 3b: Using `bytearray`

Solution 3 but with `bytes`/`bytearray` instead of `str`. Accepted in 0.619 seconds. Not sure whether it's the input/output or the `bytearray.translate` that's responsible for the speed-up:

```
import sys
from string import ascii_uppercase as abc

abc = abc.encode()
tables = {c: bytearray.maketrans(abc, abc[i:] + abc[:i])
          for i, c in enumerate(abc, 1)}

lines = map(bytes.strip, sys.stdin.buffer)
write = sys.stdout.buffer.write
for key in lines:
    if key == b'0':
        break
    plaintext = next(lines)

    ciphertext = bytearray(plaintext)
    n = len(key)
    for i, k in enumerate(key):
        ciphertext[i::n] = ciphertext[i::n].translate(tables[k])

    write(ciphertext)
    write(b'\n')
```

Comment: This is a good answer -- well done. I had a couple beers and typed my response without thinking too hard about the algorithm. Anyway, I encourage the OP to focus on this reply, but I'll leave my answer up, because it does have some useful points about how to set up an overall program in a useful way for experimentation.

Answer (score 3):

Start with some of the low-hanging fruit. (1) Inside your primary for-loop, you
repeatedly used `index()` to hunt for a value that can be easily computed in
advance. (2) You are assembling the output data via string concatenation, but
Python strings are immutable, which implies the creation of an entirely new
string on each iteration of the loop. That can become problematic when
dealing with larger inputs. Here's an edited version with those
issues in mind. It sticks fairly closely to your original code.

```
import string
import sys

# Create an dict mapping each uppercase letter to its index in
# string.ascii_uppercase. In addition, (and these changse are much less
# important) make `letters` a local variable so we don't have to perform an
# attribute lookup on `string.ascii_uppercase` inside the loop. And define
# a constant to eliminate the need to call `len()` repeatedly.
letters = string.ascii_uppercase
letter_indexes = {c : i for i, c in enumerate(letters)}
n_letters = len(letters)

while True:
    key = sys.stdin.readline().strip()

    # Simplifying the loop-break logic.
    if key == '0':
        break

    decrypted_msg = sys.stdin.readline().strip()

    # Simplifying the key-creation logic.
    # We don't care whether `key` is too long.
    key = (len(decrypted_msg)//len(key) + 1) * key

    # We will append characters to a list rather
    # than creating a fresh string each time.
    encrypted_chars = []

    for i in range(len(decrypted_msg)):
        key_idx = letter_indexes[key[i]]
        deciphered_idx = letter_indexes[decrypted_msg[i]]

        enciphered_idx = (deciphered_idx + key_idx + 1) % n_letters
        encrypted_chars.append(letters[enciphered_idx])

    # Assemble the final string.
    enciphered_msg = ''.join(encrypted_chars)
    print(enciphered_msg)
```

Your program is difficult to test and debug, due to its larger design. For
example, your linked pdf provided some sample inputs and expected outputs, but
the program itself did not provide easy ways to toggle between its "real life"
usage (reading from `stdin`, in this case) and various testing/debugging usages.
This adds friction to attempts to experiment with program, hampering the
ability to make refinements, simplifications, and speed enhancements. A more
flexible approach is to keep the Vigenère algorithm completely isolated from
the orchestration tasks of handling inputs and different usage modes.

The code below provides a sketch of a more flexible structure. It also
illustrates how to take advantage of `zip()` and `itertools.cycle()` to
simplify the code logic -- and, in particular, to rely less on manual indexing
into strings. Although this part of the answer was not intended to provide
additional speed-ups, at least in my not-very-sophisticated experiments, these
changes also made the algorithm notably faster.

Finally, the edited `vigenere()`
function provides a nice illustration of the way that **carefully chosen,
shorter variable names** can increase code readability and clarity -- provided
that those shorter names are within a narrow context (i.e., a short function)
and have sufficient contextual information (e.g., code comments and nearby
function/variable names that are more explicit).

```
import string
import sys
from itertools import cycle

# Test data from the pdf file.
TESTS = [
    ['ICPC', 'THISISSECRETMESSAGE', 'CKYVRVIHLUUWVHIVJJU'],
    ['ACM', 'CENTRALEUROPEPROGRAMMINGCONTEST', 'DHAUUNMHHSRCFSEPJEBPZJQTDRAUHFU'],
    ['LONGKEY', 'CERC', 'OTFJ'],
]

def main(args):
    if args and args[0] == 'test':
        # Make sure our vigenere() is still OK.
        for key, text, expected in TESTS:
            encrypted = vigenere(text, key)
            print(encrypted == expected, encrypted)
    else:
        # The coding challenge use case.
        while True:
            key = sys.stdin.readline().strip()
            if key == '0':
                break
            text = sys.stdin.readline().strip()
            encrypted = vigenere(text, key)
            print(encrypted)

def vigenere(text, key):
    # Takes text and a key.
    # Returns encrypted text.

    # Prepare letter index lookup.
    letters = string.ascii_uppercase
    indexes = {c : i for i, c in enumerate(letters)}
    n_letters = len(letters)

    # Encrypt the text.
    encrypted_chars = []
    for t, k in zip(text, cycle(key)):
        ti = indexes[t]
        ki = indexes[k]
        ei = (ti + ki + 1) % n_letters
        encrypted_chars.append(letters[ei])

    # Return as string.
    return ''.join(encrypted_chars)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

Comment: Good point with the separate `vigenere` function and structure. Since you didn't post times, I took the liberty to submit your solutions myself, got accepted in 1.499 seconds and 0.782 seconds. While strings are ostensibly immutable, they aren't really, and optimizations in Python/C/OS can keep the string-building with `+=` fast.

Comment: Added a [benchmarks answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/256478/219610). Oddly, your two solutions are almost equally fast. Maybe I made some mistake, but I don't see it :-)

Comment: @KellyBundy I'm not entirely surprised by that. My 2nd answer wasn't intended to provide a speed boost. It did seem faster in a "test" I ran (I just multiplied the input text to make it 50000x longer, and used Unix `time` to measure), but I wasn't rigorous at all.

Comment: Yeah, just changed that answer to say it's probably more odd that the difference was so large on the judge site.

Comment: @KellyBundy Regarding the performance of large-scale string concatenation, I understand your point. But over the years I have observed real impacts – not disastrous ones (affirming your main point), but still significant (indicating that it's good practice to behave *as if* strings were immutable under the hood). If we take my v1 code and use the pdf example inputs (multiplied in size to 50000x), I get the following from Unix `time`: 1.6 sec for string-concatenation (using `+=`) vs 1.3 sec for list-append. Admittedly, not the most robust test, but the result agrees with past recollections.

Comment: Yes, I agree `''.join` is better. At first, my list of comments didn't even include that even though my code did, I guess I'm so used to it that I forgot I had done it :-). I took another look at your solutions at the judge site. Originally I had submitted them as-is (since they're made for that), now I also submitted the first one after putting the algorithm and all its variables into a function. That made it almost as fast as your second solution there (see comments under my newer answer). So apparently the *function*-local variables are the main reason your second solution is faster.

Answer (score 2):

**Benchmarking** a worst-case (key with 1,000 random letters and plaintext with 100,000 random letters).

As @FMc [pointed out](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/256454/219610), isolating the Vigenère algorithm in a function is helpful. Here I do that for benchmarking.

**Benchmark results:**

```
74.76 ms  73.98 ms  73.28 ms  original
 8.97 ms   8.34 ms   8.01 ms  Kelly_Bundy_1
20.81 ms  20.70 ms  21.24 ms  Kelly_Bundy_2
 4.28 ms   4.18 ms   4.10 ms  Kelly_Bundy_3
22.58 ms  22.18 ms  22.62 ms  FMc_1
21.22 ms  20.92 ms  21.62 ms  FMc_2
```

I'm quite happy to see that my third solution (encrypting entire slices with `str.translate`) is fastest at this. So apparently the judge site's test suite differs significantly from this worst case.

**Benchmark code:**

```
def main():

    from timeit import repeat
    import random
    import string
    
    funcs = original, Kelly_Bundy_1, Kelly_Bundy_2, Kelly_Bundy_3, FMc_1, FMc_2
        
    def random_string(length):
        return ''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_uppercase, k=length))

    key = random_string(1_000)
    plaintext = random_string(100_000)
    number = 10

    args = key, plaintext

    # Correctness
    expect = original(*args)
    for func in funcs:
        result = func(*args)
        print(result == expect, func.__name__)
        if result != expect:
            print(len(expect), len(result), expect[:20], result[:20])
    print()

    # Speed
    tss = [[] for _ in funcs]
    for _ in range(3):
        for func, ts in zip(funcs, tss):
            t = min(repeat(lambda: func(*args), number=number)) / number
            ts.append(t)
            print(*('%5.2f ms ' % (t * 1e3) for t in ts), func.__name__)
        print()


def prep_original():
    import string
    return string,

def original(key, decrypted_msg, prepped=prep_original()):
    string, = prepped

    key = (len(decrypted_msg)//len(key) + 1) * key
    key = key[0:len(decrypted_msg)]

    encrypted_msg = ""

    for i in range(len(decrypted_msg)):
        key_idx = string.ascii_uppercase.index(key[i])
        deciphered_idx = string.ascii_uppercase.index(decrypted_msg[i])

        enciphered_idx = (deciphered_idx + key_idx + 1) % len(string.ascii_uppercase)
        encrypted_msg += string.ascii_uppercase[enciphered_idx]

    return encrypted_msg


def prep_Kelly_Bundy_1():
    from itertools import cycle
    from string import ascii_uppercase as abc
    table = {(abc[i], abc[j]): abc[(i + j + 1) % 26]
             for i in range(26)
             for j in range(26)}.get
    return cycle, table

def Kelly_Bundy_1(key, plaintext, prepped=prep_Kelly_Bundy_1()):
    cycle, table = prepped
    
    return ''.join(map(table, zip(plaintext, cycle(key))))


def prep_Kelly_Bundy_2():
    from string import ascii_uppercase as abc
    from itertools import cycle
    index = abc.index
    bcd = abc[1:] + abc
    return cycle, index, bcd
    
def Kelly_Bundy_2(key, plaintext, prepped=prep_Kelly_Bundy_2()):
    cycle, index, bcd = prepped
    
    key = cycle(map(index, key))
    plaintext = map(index, plaintext)
    
    return ''.join([bcd[p + k] for p, k in zip(plaintext, key)])


def prep_Kelly_Bundy_3():
    from string import ascii_uppercase as abc
    tables = {c: str.maketrans(abc, abc[i:] + abc[:i])
              for i, c in enumerate(abc, 1)}
    return tables,

def Kelly_Bundy_3(key, plaintext, prepped=prep_Kelly_Bundy_3()):
    tables, = prepped

    ciphertext = [None] * len(plaintext)
    n = len(key)
    for i, k in enumerate(key):
        ciphertext[i::n] = plaintext[i::n].translate(tables[k])

    return ''.join(ciphertext)


def prep_FMc_1():
    import string
    letters = string.ascii_uppercase
    letter_indexes = {c : i for i, c in enumerate(letters)}
    n_letters = len(letters)
    return letters, letter_indexes, n_letters

def FMc_1(key, decrypted_msg, prepped=prep_FMc_1()):
    letters, letter_indexes, n_letters = prepped
    
    key = (len(decrypted_msg)//len(key) + 1) * key
    encrypted_chars = []

    for i in range(len(decrypted_msg)):
        key_idx = letter_indexes[key[i]]
        deciphered_idx = letter_indexes[decrypted_msg[i]]

        enciphered_idx = (deciphered_idx + key_idx + 1) % n_letters
        encrypted_chars.append(letters[enciphered_idx])

    enciphered_msg = ''.join(encrypted_chars)
    return enciphered_msg


def prep_FMc_2():
    import string
    from itertools import cycle
    letters = string.ascii_uppercase
    indexes = {c : i for i, c in enumerate(letters)}
    n_letters = len(letters)
    return cycle, letters, indexes, n_letters

def FMc_2(key, text, prepped=prep_FMc_2()):
    cycle, letters, indexes, n_letters = prepped

    encrypted_chars = []
    for t, k in zip(text, cycle(key)):
        ti = indexes[t]
        ki = indexes[k]
        ei = (ti + ki + 1) % n_letters
        encrypted_chars.append(letters[ei])
    return ''.join(encrypted_chars)

main()
```

**Why does this differ from the judge site?** Why is my third solution *slower* than my other two there, when it's faster here? As I explained in my other answer, the intuition for why it could be faster is that the length limits of 1,000 for the key and 100,000 for the plaintext suggest that the plaintext might typically be 100 times longer than the key. Or at least that there are a few test cases at those limits, which would dominate the overall ratio (small cases don't contribute much to the totals and thus to the overall ratio unless there are really many of them). So my third solution is based on the assumption that the total length of all plaintexts divided by the total length of all keys is about 100, making the overhead of using `str.translate` worth it. But it turns out that the real ratio is only between 2.14 and 2.15, as can be tested with this code that gets accepted (note the assertion at the end):

```
import sys
from itertools import cycle
from string import ascii_uppercase as abc

table = {(abc[i], abc[j]): abc[(i + j + 1) % 26]
         for i in range(26)
         for j in range(26)}.get

k = p = 0

lines = map(str.strip, sys.stdin)
for key in lines:
    if key == '0':
        break
    plaintext = next(lines)

    k += len(key)
    p += len(plaintext)

    print(''.join(map(table, zip(plaintext, cycle(key)))))

assert 2.14 < p / k < 2.15
```

Comment: @Peilonrayz That judge is pretty consistent. I had already noticed that in my previous 43 submissions for this problem, and now I submitted FMc's two solutions again, each five times, alternating between the two (just like I cycle through the solutions in my benchmark, btw). The first solution took 1.372, 1.372, 1.378, 1.439, 1.368 seconds and the second took 0.759, 0.765, 0.775, 0.775, 0.779 seconds.

Comment: Oh wow. Those are some consistent timings.

Comment: @Peilonrayz Submitted FMc's first solution twice more, after modifying it just by putting stuff into a function. Improved to 0.839 and 0.836 seconds that way. Previously I had just submitted it as-is. So apparently most of the speed difference came from the speed of local vs global variables.